# how to set R resources array onto a string Array

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays

how to set R resources array onto a string Array

I Try this, but I get an error as:

```
12-10 16:10:24.793: E/AndroidRuntime(22575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 16:10:24.793: E/AndroidRuntime(22575): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java.lang.String[] of length 2131230728 exceeds the VM limit
12-10 16:10:24.793: E/AndroidRuntime(22575):    at com.dec.myapp.fragments.EditUserProfileFragment.onCreateView(EditUserProfileFragment.java:102)
12-10 16:10:24.793: E/AndroidRuntime(22575):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
12-10 16:10:24.793: E/AndroidRuntime(22575):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
12-10 16:10:24.793: E/AndroidRuntime(22575):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
12-10 16:10:24.793: E/AndroidRuntime(22575):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
12-10 16:10:24.793: E/AndroidRuntime(22575):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
12-10 16:10:24.793: E/AndroidRuntime(22575):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
```

this is my code

```
String[] mCountry = new String[R.array.countries_array];
```

in XML

```
<string-array name="countries_array">
    <item>Afghanistan</item>
    <item>Albania</item>
    <item>Algeria</item>
    <item>American Samoa</item>
    <item>Andorra</item>
...
```

Comment: are you trying this on emulator..??

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `getStringArray()` function for getting string arrays..

**Code :**

```
String[] mCountry;

mCountry= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
```

**References :**

```
public String[] getStringArray (int id)
    Return the string array associated with a particular resource ID.
```

Refer this for more : [Developer's Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getStringArray(int))

Answer (score 2):

The array is your resource, so you access it by doing following

```
  Resources resources=getResources();
  String[] mCountry=resources.getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
```

or just in one line

```
String[] mCountry=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
```

For further references [See this too](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: This is duplicate answer

Comment: @VicJordan I will let the **timestamp** help you,I was just typing when the other answer was posted anyway

Comment: @VicJordan No, there's no evidence that it's a duplicate answer. In facts, it seems a genuine answer.

Comment: @nobalG Der, I was reading this question and during that first answer appeared was from Prag's then this answer.

Comment: no offence for his answer.. It happens... Thnk u for your support.. @VicJordan

Comment: This was just my observation, didn't have intention to hurt anyone. Please don't mind guys. Happy coding :) :)

Comment: I respect your observation.. Thank you for it.. Happy Coding to you too.. @VicJordan